# $.post keeps redirecting me

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have problem with jquery $.post function. I use this function a lot and same function works fine except in one case and I don't understand why it keeps redirecting me after script was executed, here is js code:

```
var record;    

$('.delbtt').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var deleteid = $(this).parent().parent().find('#id').text();
        record = $(this).parent().parent();
        $('#delrecord').empty().val(deleteid);
    });

$(document).on('submit', '#delteform', function() {
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        $.post('includes/delete.php',formData,processData);
        function processData(data){
            record.remove();    
        };
    });
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteFormModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="deleteform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="includes/delete.php" method="POST"> <!-- -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete record</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this person?</p>
            </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="delrecord" name="delrecord" value="" />
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default empty" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="delentry" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Person</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I know that function is executed successfully, because if I put `alert("Why is this not working?");` after `record.remove();`, I can see alert and in background code executed, but instead of staying at the same page it redirects me to 'includes/delete.php'. I tried disabling all other $.post functions that I have in my JS, I tried using `$('#deleteform').submit()`, I tried putting it outside of my main `$(document).ready(function() {});` same results... Always same result it redirects me after function completes instead of staying on a page. Does anybody have idea why am I getting this behavior?

php code:

```
<?php
include('budgetprop/Initialize.php');
Database::GetInstance()->ConnectToServer($errors);
$record = $_POST['delrecord'];

# CONNECT TO DB
if(Database::GetInstance()->ConnectToServer($errors)){
    $insertSQL1 = "DELETE FROM salaries WHERE record_id = '".$record."' ";
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query(Database::GetInstance()->databaseConnection, $insertSQL1);
    # IF THERE IS AN ERROR
    if(!$stmt1){
                echo "Error, cannot delete record"; 
    }else{
        Database::GetInstance()->LastInsertId($stmt1);
    }
    # IF ALL QUERIES WERE SUCCSESSFUL, COMMIT THE TRANSACTION, OTHERWISE ROLLBACK
    if($stmt1 && !$errors){
        sqlsrv_commit(Database::GetInstance()->databaseConnection);
        # FREE THE STATEMENT
        Database::GetInstance()->FreeDBStatement($stmt1);
        echo "success";
        return true;
    }else{
        sqlsrv_rollback(Database::GetInstance()->databaseConnection);
        # FREE THE STATEMENT
        Database::GetInstance()->FreeDBStatement($stmt1);
        return false;
    }
    # NO CONNECTION WAS MADE
}else{
    return false;
};
?>
```

`preventDefault()` doesn't work either

Comment: In what way is this PHP related?

Comment: `prevent.Default()` is incorrect.  That's not what it says in the code I posted.

Comment: @archer, my bad, mistyped

Comment: Another typo, I hope - you're handling submit events for `#delteform`, but the form is called `deleteform`.

Comment: @Archer, I can't believe, such a stupid mistake, that correction and adding preventDefault() resolved. Just correcting to `#deleteform` didn't help

Comment: Easily done!  Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your form is still being submitted, hence the redirect.  You can stop it with `preventDefault()`...

```
$(document).on('submit', '#deleteform', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('includes/delete.php',formData,processData);
    function processData(data){
        record.remove();    
    };
});
```

Comment: yes, adding the JS submit handler does not, by itself, prevent the HTML submit handler from occurring, so your handler is running and then the form is submitting as it normally would.

Comment: `post` will not do a redirect, so something else is definitely doing it.  Can you show us the form and `record.remove()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "deleteform" is the ID of a form element on your page, within which you have an input or button of type "submit", I would suggest changing the delentry button to have a type of "button".

Most browsers will perform a POST/GET on a form that has an input or button of type submit when that button is clicked.

I would then update your jQuery event handler to select the button and specify an onclick event:

```
$('#delentry').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

If you wish to maintain some form of graceful degradation, you could leave the markup as a submit type button and on $(document).ready(), update the type of the button to be "button".